# MS SQL - Как переместить кластерный индекс в другую файловую группу?

Tags: sql-server

MS SQL 2008 R2

Comment: @Михаил Беляев, если Вам помог ответ - жмакните по галке слева под кулчаком вниз. ![alt text][1]  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/Qe5BY.png(взято из ответа @shaman888)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, как-то [так](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms175905.aspx)?

Пардон, не заметил версию... [2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms175905(v=sql.105).aspx)